# Hudson / Jenkins - transfer files from linux to windows

Tags: linux, jenkins, scripting, sftp, hudson

We have hudson installed on linux server. We have created jobs to checkout source files from SVN and build respective jars/wars (which is placed at a location on the linux server called "BuildArea").

We have another location called "ReleaseArea" on a windows server where we keep the build artifacts so that it can be used for further activities.

My requirement is to create a Hudson job which will automatically update the ReleaseArea by copying/transferring the files from BuildArea (Linux Server) to ReleaseArea (Windows Server).

NOTE:
we have tried it using pscp option from windows server but we are not able to use that through a hudson job as hudson is installed on linux.

We are specifically trying to implement this task via hudson.

Any suggestions/comments or alternative best solution always welcome.

Thanks,
Rohan Shetty

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. You've described your requirements, but you don't say what difficulty you're having in developing this. What specific problem do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer files from Jenkins installed Linux machine to Windows share using [Publish Over CIFS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin)